# Promise not iterable? Error with functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting up a new Firebase Cloud Functions to work with my app on Android. All I want to do is send a notification to some `token_ids` when a new record has writed to the database. But on my Javascript code, I get an error :

> < Promise > is not iterable

in following line:

```
const results = await Promise.all(getDeviceTokensPromise);
```

The function is triggered, so it detects correctly the new write/record on the database. But it doesn't send any notification.

Hope someone can bring some light to this. Thanks in advance.

On my Databse, the tokens list are indexed like:

```
/tokens
   /Vilanova
      /-LoReasGHj88MhbEj2Fn
        token:"xxxxxxxx"

      /-LoRf1fAA2ZhIu6JMLW7
        token:"xxxxxxxx"
```

This is the function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//Evento Trigger On Write para nuevas alertas
exports.sendUsuariosNotification = functions.database.ref('/alertas/Vilanova/{alertaid}')
    .onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {

// Referencia a lista de tokens en Vilanova
    const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/tokens/Vilanova/{tokenid}`).once('value');

// Snapshop para los tokens
    let tokensSnapshot;

    // Array para los tokens
    let tokens;

    const results = await Promise.all(getDeviceTokensPromise);
    tokensSnapshot = results;

// Si no se encuentran tokens, mostramos en log
    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        return console.log('No hay tokens disponibles para enviar notificaciones');
    }


console.log('Hay', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens para mandar notificaciones.');

//Información de la notificación
                const payload = {
                        "data": {
                                "title": "Nueva alerta",
                                "body": "",
                                "icon": "ic_launcher",
                                "sound": "default",
                            }
        }

// Listando los tokens en array
    tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Envio de notificaciones a todos los tokens
    const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

    // Variable para comprobar si ha ocurrido un error con algún token
const tokensToRemove = [];

response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            console.error('fallo al enviar notificacion a :', tokens[index], error);

            // Limpiamos los tokens no registrados o invalidos.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                    error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {

                    tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
            }
        }
  });

  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);

});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all notes that you need pass an iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `getDeviceTokensPromise` is a promise, not an array. `Promise.all` expects an **array** of promises as its argument (well, not necessarily an array, but an iterable). I suspect you just want:

```
const results = await getDeviceTokensPromise;
```

...and that `getDeviceTokensPromise`'s fulfillment value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference.html#once

It is a promise, not an array of promise

`const results = await getDeviceTokensPromise` will do